# How to automatically accept epel gpg key

Tags: package-management, rpm, gpg

The very first time that I install a package from epel, I am prompted if I want to import a GPG key.

Notice how there are 2 'Is this ok' prompts when installing redis?

```
[root@us-devops-build02 yum.repos.d]# yum install redis
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
.. truncated for readability

Total download size: 213 k
Installed size: 668 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
redis-2.4.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 213 kB     00:00     
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Retrieving key from http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
Importing GPG key 0x0608B895:
 Userid: "EPEL (6) <epel@fedoraproject.org>"
 From  : http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

This causes puppet to fail on freshly-provisioned machines, unless I ssh in to the machine first and manually accept the installation of this key.

1. Why does epel need a key to be downloaded on the first installation of a package?
2. How can I automatically install this key on my images so puppet won't fail?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason yum is asking for a key is that it is not present in /etc/pki/rpm-gpg

```
ls /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/ | column
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6        RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Security-6    RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6
RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-6    RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
```

You can import the key in one of 4 ways:

1. use `rpm --import http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6` 
   (as suggested by slm)
2. Install a package and then wait for the prompt (like I was doing)
3. Use the RPM package provided by epel, it installs the repo and the key simultaneously.

   `sudo yum -y install http://mirror.pnl.gov/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm"`
4. Manually copy the key to the right directory.

Comment: You should not blindly accept a key downloaded over insecure HTTP. Make sure to validate it somehow (e.g., check SHA256) or use HTTPS.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate: At least as of RHEL/CentOS 8, adding keys to "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg" does not make them trusted by the package manager. Instead, they have to be added to the RPM system's key store. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659625/16227) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Any repository worth its salt will sign the RPMs that it delivers. The key used to confirm the signing of the RPMs is what you're downloading and installing this first time.

Without this key it would be impossible to guarantee the authenticity of the RPMs from a given repository, so this is a extremely important feature that should not be quickly dismissed as annoying.

If you want to automatically install the key you can try installing the key directly, prior to installing any RPMs from a repository like so:

```
$ rpm --import <url>

-or-

$ yum -y ...
```

#### Examples

```
$ sudo rpm --import \
    http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Or you could try setting the option to `yum` to assume yes:

```
$ yum -y install redis
```

You could also download these files manually and put them in this directory, `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/`. The next time `yum` or `rpm` runs they'll pick these files up that are present here.

#### References

- [GPG KEYS USED BY FEDORA PROJECT](https://fedoraproject.org/keys)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things happening here with regard to package/repo signing:

- Keys (for default repos) are stored in "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg". However, this is just a storage location for reference and does not make them trusted by the package manager (at least as of RHEL/CentOS 8).
- Repo configurations (in "/etc/yum.repos.d") define the URL of a GPG public key with which the repo and packages are signed. For the default repos, that key URL typically has a `file://` scheme referring to keys from "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg". In your case, the EPEL config refers to an `http://` URL instead. This of course means you initially obtain the key over an insecure channel, effectively creating a [TOFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) situation.
- For package installation, the key must be imported into the RPM system's key store. The second prompt you're seeing is about that. `rpm --import` allows you to add keys manually before installing packages. See [How to verify Linux packages before installing them](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rpm-gpg-verify-packages) for additional information on managing that key store.
- In addition to the default signatures of packages, signature checks [on repository metadata](https://blog.centos.org/2018/07/improving-centos-package-delivery-security-with-signed-repository-metadata/) may be enabled by setting `repo_gpgcheck=1` in the repo configuration. For that, keys must be imported into yet another key store located at "/var/lib/yum/*/gpgdir" (legacy) or "/var/cache/dnf/*/pubring" (RHEL/CentOS 8). When the keys have not yet been added to these stores, you may be also be asked to import them – and the prompt for that look just like the one for the RPM key store.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet ?
Drop the certificate inside of a puppet code bundle. That way you are only dependent on the security of the main puppet machine.

Have the code bundle install the certificate.